# How to calculate base64image String size in MB?

Tags: javascript, temenos-quantum

I am taking a picture and i am converting it into Base64 string. And i am able to calculate the size of the picture in KB. I need to know the formula to calculate the size in MB. Please clarify.

The below code works fine for calculating size in KB.

```
function onCameraClick() {
      var base64Val = kony.convertToBase64(frmImageSize.camCamera.rawBytes);
      var imageSizeinKB = base64Val.length*0.75 )/1024;        
}
```

Comment: 1 MB = 1024 KB so just divide your KB by 1024,  var sizeInMB = imageSizeinKB/1024

Answer (score 0):

For your reference:
1024 bytes = 1 KB 
1024 KB = 1 MB
1024 MB   = 1 GB
1024 GB = 1 TB

So if you have arrived result in KB, to get the result in MB please divide it by 1024.

Result in MB = result in KB/1024.